# While loop runs once

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, while-loop

I am trying to run a program that will repeatedly read a letter from the user, with the most being entered as 12. If the user enters a sentinel value that they input, the loop should terminate. However, as soon as the first character is read in the loop, it terminates.

Also, the program will place the same word in the reverse order in another array, then check them to see if the first array (read forward), is the same as the other array (read backward). If it is, it displays that the word is a palindrome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
int charCount, counter, i, temp, check,check2;
char  letter[12], letter2[12];
charCount = 0;
counter = 10;
check = 0;
i = 1;
check2 = 0;

printf("Enter your sentinel value.:");
scanf_s(" %c", &letter[check2]);


while ((i<13) && (letter[i] != letter[check2]))
{
    printf("Enter individual letters in word (in order).:");
    scanf_s(" %c", &letter[i]);

    charCount++;

    if (letter[i] == letter[check2])
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;

}


printf("Letters entered:%i\n", charCount);


for (i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
{
    letter2[i] = letter[i];
}

for (i = 0; i <= (charCount / 2); i++)
{
    temp = letter2[counter];
    letter2[counter] = letter2[i];
    letter2[i] = temp;
    counter--;
}

for (i = 0; i <= charCount; i++)
{
    if (letter[i] = letter2[i])
    {
        check++;
    }
}

if (check = charCount)
{
    printf("Word is a palindrome.\n");
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: 1) `scanf_s(" %c", &letter[check2]);` --> `scanf_s(" %c", &letter[check2], 1);`

Comment: @MooingDuck see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Comment: 2) `(i<13)`  -> `(i<12)`

Comment: 3) `if (letter[i] = letter2[i])`, `if (check = charCount)` : `=` --> `==`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Whoa, how did I never notice that bit before?  `Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in [].`

Comment: 4) `(letter[i] != letter[check2])` : `letter[i]` uninitialize.

Comment: 5) `for (i = 0; i < charCount; i++) { letter2[i] = letter[i]; }` : `charCount`  is one less than the actual number of characters

Comment: 5-1) or Sentinel letter is included.

Answer (score 0):

the  letter[1] value will be unassigned when the while loop enters for the first time right ? I think you can take that condition out of the while loop since you are considering it in the if statement inside the while loop